# Object scaling (resize image, button, text and panel) in Java Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8

I'm using Java Netbeans to develop my display software like this: [original display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndUBN.png), but when i set fullscreen display to: [maximize display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQ1AT.png) that's object content (picture, text, button, panel, etc.) size didn't change.

I've found the methode to image scaling, but it's manually that's object (not all of the object in entire JFrame). There is any easier way to change all of my object content to resize automatically in Java Neatbeans?

Thanks...

Comment: Please describe your problem more detailed and what you expect.